# Location Tracking?

Tags: android, timer, location, tracking, intervals

We have a requirement of tracking user location using our android application. Users have application installed in their phone. But we are facing a problem, in some cases e.g app going in background, device locked application does not send locations.

How to make sure that application send location update at regular interval irrespective of app being in foreground/background.

We are using API 24 and fused-location-provider.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [project](https://github.com/NeilSayok/Car-Locator-System) on github. It might help you.
This app sends location updates every 3 seconds to the server and is not killed even if the device is locked or if the app gets in background.